# Adding a value to a column based on other values in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
ID   d1   d2   
1    G    G
2    A    G
3    A    A
4    G    A
5    NA   NA
6    G    G
```

I want to add another column based on the values of d1 and d2

```
ID   d1   d2    new  
1    G    G     GG
2    A    G     AG
3    A    A     AA
4    G    A     GA   
5    NA   NA    NA
6    G    G     GG
```

Comment: I guess the last one would be `GG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
df1$new <- with(df1, ifelse(is.na(d1)|is.na(d2), NA, paste0(d1, d2)))
df1$new
#[1] "GG" "AG" "AA" "GA" NA   "GG"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- within(df,new <- paste(d1,d2,sep=""))

df$new <-replace(df$new,df$new%in%"NANA",NA)

  id   d1   d2  new
1  1    G    G   GG
2  2    A    G   AG
3  3    A    A   AA
4  4    G    A   GA
5  5 <NA> <NA> <NA>
6  6    G    G   GG
```

If you want to remove NA rows from the data you can use

```
df <- within(subset(df,!is.na(d1)&!is.na(d2)),new <- paste(d1,d2,sep=""))


  id d1 d2 new
1  1  G  G  GG
2  2  A  G  AG
3  3  A  A  AA
4  4  G  A  GA
6  6  G  G  GG
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `mutate` function from the `dplyr` package.